# How to draw a rectangle and adjust its shape by drag and drop in PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qpainter, qmouseevent

I'm trying to draw a rectangle on GUI created by PyQt5 by drag and drop. I managed to do that, but the rectangle is drawn when the mouse left key is released.

What I want to do is like this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=61pkLt9rWPE):

- When the mouse left button is pressed, start drawing the rectangle.
- While dragging, adjust the rectangle shape with the mouse movement.
- When the mouse left button is released, determine the rectangle shape.

How can I implement this? Thanks in advance.

Here's my code.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter

class MyWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(30,30,600,400)
        self.pos1 = [0,0]
        self.pos2 = [0,0]
        self.show()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        width = self.pos2[0]-self.pos1[0]
        height = self.pos2[1] - self.pos1[1]     

        qp = QPainter()
        qp.begin(self)           
        qp.drawRect(self.pos1[0], self.pos1[1], width, height)        
        qp.end()

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.pos1[0], self.pos1[1] = event.pos().x(), event.pos().y()
        print("clicked")

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.pos2[0], self.pos2[1] = event.pos().x(), event.pos().y()
        print("released")
        self.update()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWidget()
    window.show()
    app.aboutToQuit.connect(app.deleteLater)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You do not have to use the `mouseReleaseEvent` function, but the `mouseMoveEvent` function that is called each time the mouse is moved, and I have modified the code to make it simpler.

```
class MyWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(30,30,600,400)
        self.begin = QtCore.QPoint()
        self.end = QtCore.QPoint()
        self.show()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        qp = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        br = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(100, 10, 10, 40))  
        qp.setBrush(br)   
        qp.drawRect(QtCore.QRect(self.begin, self.end))       

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.begin = event.pos()
        self.end = event.pos()
        self.update()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        self.end = event.pos()
        self.update()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.begin = event.pos()
        self.end = event.pos()
        self.update()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and modifying my code. This is exactly what I've been looking for.

Comment: If I draw another rectangle previous rectangle vanishes. Why?

Comment: Because PaintEvent blanks the canvas and draws precisely one line. If you want to keep the line and draw others you'll need to keep a list of lines that PaintEvent paints, adding to it with each drop.