# How PyQT5 draw line move with mouse?

Tags: python, pyqt5

Im new in using PyQT5, now I need a function that as the mouse moves and draw a rectangle with the mouse as the center, could anybody help?

Comment: Have you tried something? If yes, please show us what you've done so far, even if it doesn't work as expected. Otherwise, please consider that StackOverflow is not a code service nor a tutorial website, we answer to specific, detailed answers. Please take your time to follow the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to draw a rectangle and adjust its shape by drag and drop in PyQt5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44468775/how-to-draw-a-rectangle-and-adjust-its-shape-by-drag-and-drop-in-pyqt5)

Comment: Thank you. I've solved it. I'll publish my code later